# Change filed in byte representation of JSON object

Tags: go

I write `A` object to a file `f`.

```
a := A{42}
bytes, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a, "", "\t")
f.Write(bytes)
```

Where `A` looks like:

```
type A struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
}
```

Then I change field of this object and write it to the file:

```
a.A = 666
f.Write(bytes)
```

As a result, I see only

```
{
    "a": 42
}{
    "a": 42
}
```

While I expected:

```
{
    "a": 42
}{
    "a": 666
}
```

I know that I can overcome it by using `json.MarshalIndent` again. But I need to do a lot of (~10^6) writings to the file, so using  `json.MarshalIndent` again and again seems to be a heavy task.

How can I directly change a `bytes` variable?

Code is located at https://play.golang.org/p/8CMpwehMidR

Comment: Changing a has no influence on the marshaled data: You need to marshal the new value again, to get a new JSON.

Comment: "I know that I can overcome it by using json.MarshalIndent again. But I need to do a lot of (~10^6) writings to the file, so using  json.MarshalIndent again and again seems to be a heavy task." ** 

Try it out. It might turn out to not be a heavy task after all. When you write to a file, it does not necessarily get written to the disk immediately. Writes are buffered and flushed to disk once there's some amount of data collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no choice but to marshal repeatedly. Use a [*json.Encoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder) for improved ergonomics and efficiency:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type A struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("foo.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    enc := json.NewEncoder(f)
    enc.SetIndent("", "\t")

    a := A{42} // Using a pointer may improve performance if A is large.
    enc.Encode(a)

    a.A = 666
    enc.Encode(a)
}
```

Wrapping the file with a [buffered writer](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewWriter) may also improve performance, depending on how quickly you can compute successive values for the As and how fast the disk is.

Comment: Does `json.NewEncoder` support adding delimiters in `json` file? Or I have to do it manually?

Comment: I've checked it out. It doesn't add delimiters between objects. Maybe you know the way how to get a valid JSON after writing to a file?

Comment: @RomaKarageorgievich, it does add a single newline character (`'\n'`) after each JSON document. The output here is pretty much equivalent to what you have in your question; several consecutive, valid JSON documents. Any JSON stream reader can process this as-is. You have to explain what you mean by "valid JSON".

Comment: Yes, output from `*json.Encoder` is similar to mine. Valid json vs invalid json I represente here https://play.golang.org/p/WArVYimolko

Comment: That's different then. You'll want to build a slice (`[]A`) and then marshal once, or write the additional tokens (`[],`) manually.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the standard library to replace bytes within the given bytes slice.

https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Replace

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type A struct {
    A int `json:"a"`
}

func main() {
    out := bufio.NewWriterSize(os.Stdout, 20)
    // defer out.Flush() // commented for demonstration purpose. Uncomment this to finalize the flush.
    a := A{42}
    b, _ := json.MarshalIndent(a, "", "\t")
    out.Write(b)
    b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("42"), []byte("666"), -1)
    out.Write(b)
}
```

It is not recommended to do it, but ultimately this is possible.

I included a buffered writer for demonstration of others answers and comments, don t forget to flush it.